# C# generics and understanding nested generic types

Tags: java, c#

Say I have the following type

```
public inteface IA<T1,T2> where T1 : IB<T2> where T2 : IC {}
```

Then why do i have to supply T1,T2 in the implementation class. Should it not be possible for C# to automatically wire these?

Now you have to write the implementation class as follows

```
class A : IA<B,C> {}

class B : IB<C> {}

class C : IC {}
```

However it would be better if it could be written as

```
class A : IA<B>
```

Which i guess should be possible for the compiler to interpret given that B -> C in its implementation?

In order for this to work IA should be written as follows:

```
public interface IA<T1<T2>> where T1 : IB<T2> where T2 : IC {}
```

I believe this is possible in the Java world, so why not c#?

Comment: Because it wasn't built that way - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/

Comment: As an example of why they didn't do it that way. Let's say you expected `class A : IA<B>` to compile. Then `B` was changed to `class B : IB<C>, IB<D> {}` What would you expect the compiler to do?

Comment: @mjwills I guess it should fail compilation as it no longer has the same signature as expected by IA.